# What are the correct file permissions for a Django project in virtual environment located in home folder?

Tags: django, server, file-permissions

In the context of a production environment, what are the correct file permissions for a Django project in virtual environment located in home folder?

Apparently it is not good practice to install a venv in /var/www

I am using Django 2.0 on Ubuntu 16, and have it installed in ~/myvevnv/ i.e. in my home directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All `venvs` should be stored in `~/.virtualenvs`.